# Laravel 5.2 - method [ajax] does not exist

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I've been trying to create an upload page for a webapplication. For sending the files to the server I want to use AJAX, as I've been using AJAX GETs for the whole front-end.

My problem is that when trying to use POST, under the circumstances I will provide you with in a moment, I get the error message 'Method [ajax] does not exist'.

My route (the POST one):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'organisatie', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'ajax'], 'namespace' => 'Organisatie'], function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{organisatie}/documenten'], function ()
    {
        Route::get('/', 'DriveController@index')->name('drive.index');
        Route::post('/upload', 'DriveController@upload')->name('drive.upload');
    });
});
```

The route would come down to `organisatie/{organisatie_id}/documenten/upload`.

My `DriveController@upload`:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file[]');

    return response()->json($file);
}
```

My AJAX code:

```
var formData = new FormData();

utility.foreach(upload.fileArray.array, function (file) {
    formData.append('file[]', file);
});

var ajax = {
    url: '/organisatie/1/documenten/upload',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
};

$.ajax(ajax);
```

Note:

- `utility.foreach` is my own foreach implementation, and it does just
  that.
- `upload.fileArray` is an array wrapper I defined and it works as
  expected.
- Populating the `upload.fileArray` works fine and is tested. It's populated from an `input[type=file] (multiple)`'s `FileList`.

Any and all help is appreciated. Please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Is your ajax middleware properly set up?

Comment: your problem lies with `$.ajax(ajax);` because you probably haven't included jQuery (correcly). http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: try to search in your page source after the page loads, to find the jQuery library you include and paste it here . for example i use `<script src="path_to_jquery_file/jquery-2.1.1.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I do have jQuery set up properly. @Neat I'm not sure, as I am not familiar with that just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. Neat's answer inspired me to check my Route set up, and it appeared that you should still use `?ajax=functionName` on POST routes. In my case:

Route:

```
Route::post('/', 'DriveController@index')->name('drive.upload.post');
```

AJAX:

```
var ajax = {
    url: '/organisatie/1/documenten?ajax=upload', <--- '/upload' to '?ajax=upload'
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
};
```

with `DriveController@upload -> DriveController@ajaxUpload`

For some reason I couldn't find this answer anywhere, so I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This might seem obvious to some, but for me it took a lot of time before I figured out what the problem was, so hopefully this will help someone who's been without coffee a little too long.